# Xcode 4 / Cannot understand why some symbols are missing when debugging

Tags: xcode, debugging, debug-symbols

I recently switched to Xcode 4 and the debug process is confusing. I read the Xcode manual but still cannot understand why some symbols cannot be displayed by gdb when putting the pointer onto it in the editor or when doing "po xxxxxx" where xxxx is the symbol name. I get the message "Unable to access variable" in an infinite loop.

This looks like some debug symbols have been removed (as if I was in release instead of debug but those concepts disappeared from Xcode). Is there something I should activate in order to have these symbols available ?

Regards,
Franz

Comment: Debug vs Release are available in the scheme settings.

Comment: Thank you. I have completed your tip in a response.

Comment: Can I add the reply to have it accepted? :)

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that none of the optimizations are on.  These include:

- Link-Time Optimization (make variables debugging disappears)
- Optimization Level (set to O0 or else certain variables may not be visible)
- Strip debug symbols

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, choose in menu bar: Products -> Manage schemes.
The play button action is listed as "Run" on a list on the lest. Click on the small arrow near "Run", since "play" can be associated with a "release" or "debug" build.
In pop-up menu, switch to "debug".
I now can see some variables with po xxxxx in the gdb windows. I also can see variable values when passing the pointer on the variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Edit Scheme... from the scheme bar, you can change which configurations are release and which are debug.